# Changing "I didn't think him to be so honest" into an expression of comparative degree

Tags: differences, adjectives, word-usage

> I didn't think him to be so honest.

How can we change this sentence into one of comparative degree without changing its meaning or sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write

> He was **more honest** than I thought.

Comment: Can I say,  he was more honest than I thought. ?

Comment: Sentence in past.you changed it in present. Why? Dear,

Comment: @user124234: because your sentence has '*to be* so honest', not 'to have been'. Presumably he still is honest, and when you thought about it does not change that. I think Jasper's original was better, but both versions are grammatical.